# How to compute distance values from the depth data embedded into iphone portrait pictures?

Tags: ios, iphone, computer-vision, point-clouds, depth

I am working on an application that reconstructs point cloud from the depth data.
I try to use depth data embedded in portrait images taken by some smartphones.

So far I have progress on the Google Camera app photos. It has well documented depth format (https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/Dynamic-depth-v1.0.pdf).

I am also able to extract depth related data from ios portrait pictures by uploading them to https://www.photopea.com/ or by using exiftool. Here is preview of embedded data:

[image: embedded depth image]

Unfortunately I am unable to determine actual distance values encoded to that embedded image.

There is seems to be encoding related info in xmp metadata such as

```
Stored Format = 'L008' // one component 8 bit
Native Format = 'hdis' // half precision floating point disparity
Depth Data Version = 125537 // varies
Int min value = 0
Int max value = 255
Float Min Value // for example 1.23
Float Max Value // for example 2.12
```

I tried to interpolate image data values and use it as disparity the same way google camera does

```
distance_to_camera = constant * 1.0 / (Float_Max_Value * pixel / 255 + Float_Min_Value * (1 - pixel / 255))
```

but it results in heavily distorted point cloud. I think it is likely to be incorrect depth data interpretation.

Comment: A complete example extracting far/near and depth data https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/depth-player/ but it might use another xml exif format : https://developers.google.com/depthmap-metadata/reference (eg "GDepth:Far")

Answer (score 2):

If You're working only on getting point-cloud out if depth map then You don't need actual camera-object distance. You can generate point cloud directly with some visualization library. I recommend [Vedo](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo).

Then if You need that distance information, You need to get Your camera parameters. Check out [OpenCV's tutorial about camera calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).

Comment: It seems that embedded data is not directly represents depth. I've generated dense cloud visualization and found that it is very distorted. I've tried using embedded depth data directly as a Z coordinate and also as an inverse Z (disparity, like image meta suggests).

I tried interpolating depth values / disparity between "Float Min Value" and "Float Max Value" as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is seems to be multiple type of images taken to Apple devices.

Images taken to the frontal camera (TrueDepth) has "Accuracy: absolute" mark in embedded depth XMP metadata. Disparity (~ 1 / distance) for those pictures could be calculated as linear interpolation between values "Float min value" and "Float max value" as suggested in the question.

Images taken to the rear (dual) camera has "Accuracy: relative" mark in depth XMP metadata. Disparity calculated with method above has a shift which results in depth distortion. I was not able to compensate this shift by the terms of available image metadata.

I've had iphone image dataset with different known distances and it looks like this shift is not related to any of the parameters found in XMP.

Here is a cite from AVFoundation SDK

> The accuracy of a depth data map is highly dependent on the camera
> calibration data used to generate it. If the camera's focal length
> cannot be precisely determined at the time of capture, scaling error
> in the z (depth) plane will be introduced. If the camera's optical
> center can't be precisely determined at capture time, principal point
> error will be introduced, leading to an offset error in the disparity
> estimate. AVDepthDataAccuracy constants report the accuracy of a map's
> values with respect to its reported units. If the accuracy is reported
> to be AVDepthDataAccuracyRelative, the values within the map are
> usable relative to one another (that is, larger depth values are
> farther away than smaller depth values), but do not accurately convey
> real world distance. Disparity maps with relative accuracy may still
> be used to reliably determine the difference in disparity between two
> points in the same map.